# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form' in Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to implement angular reactive forms in my angular 11 application and currently getting the error Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form' in my html

I have created a customermodule and referencing  ReactiveFormsModule. I am not sure why its still giving this error.

Customer module

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from 'src/app/shared/shared.module';

import { CustomerComponent } from '../customer/customer.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [CustomerComponent],
  imports: [
    SharedModule

  ],
  exports: [CustomerComponent]
})
export class CustomerModule { }
```

Customer component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Customer } from '../../models/customer';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer',
  templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer.component.scss']
})

export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  customerForm: FormGroup;
  customer = new Customer()

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.customerForm = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl(),
      lastName: new FormControl(),
      email: new FormControl(),
      sendCatalog: new FormControl(true)
    });

  }

  save() {

  }

}
```

Customer html

```
<div class="card-body">
  <form novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" [formGroup]="customerForm">

    <section class="flex-group">

      <div class="field">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <button type="button">Submit</button>
      </div>

    </section>


  </form>
```

App Module

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module'
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CustomerModule } from './components/customer/customer.module'
import { AnimationsModule, ElementsModule, LayoutModule, PatternsModule, WidgetsModule } from '@angloamerican/components';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    CustomerModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AnimationsModule,
    ElementsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    PatternsModule,
    WidgetsModule
  ],
  providers: [],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

App component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'AngularReactiveFormsDemo';
}
```

App html

```
<app-customer></app-customer>
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is you just imported the "CommonModule", "FormsModule" and "ReactiveFormsModule" modules in customer module in this case it will not be available to use outside.

To make available in whole application you have to export these modules.

After adding exports to your customer module,

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CustomerComponent } from '../customer/customer.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [CustomerComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  exports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, CustomerComponent]
})
export class CustomerModule { }
```

and remove "FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule" imports from app.module.ts

**Suggestion** : Don't add "CommonModule, FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule" modules in feature module. Create a module which is shared through-out the application and import that in App module(app.module.ts).

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but absolutely no difference . This is an IDE error just for your information

Comment: If possible can you share your updated "CustomerModule" file.

Comment: Shared module is not added in the post. If you don't mind can you add that also

Answer (score 0):

Try removing FormModule from the `import` in your `CustomerModule`, because it is already imported by your `AppModule` and angular doesn't like that (2 running module importing the same module).

Also does your error happens while `ng serve` or is it an IDE error ? If IDE try running it and see what's in your browser console !

You might also want to check for [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder), realy helps when playing with FormGroup

Comment: Its IDE error. No error in console. I am using Visual Studio code

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="card-body">
  <form novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" [formGroup]="customerForm">

    <section class="flex-group">

      <div class="field">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" />
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" />
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="email" />
      </div>

 <div class="field">
        <label>Catalog</label>enter code here
        <input type="text" formControlName="sendCatalog" />
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>

    </section>

  </form>
```

Comment: how does this change anything??

Comment: if you are using form group than you must have to use name or formControlName attribute with input tag